# VBA Out of Memory Error on Simple Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple code I'm trying to run, here:

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim Diff As Range, cell As Range
Set Diff = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("N:S")
For Each cell In Diff
If cells.Value2 > 0.1 Then
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, right at the If statement, I get runtime 7: Out of Memory.  I'm running this on a fairly small data set (<5,000 cells), and have closed all other programs/ unnecessary processes, and task manager shows plenty of memory.  I have no idea what could be causing this at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have any cells in Columns N:S that have text instead of numbers or errors?

Comment: Either you've got a typo (`cells.Value2` instead of `cell` that you're using in the `for each` - you don't have a variable named `cells` declared anywhere) or you've got erroneous data in one or more cells.

Comment: I think @KenWhite has found the source of your error but on a related note, why not conditional formatting?

Comment: @KenWhite You were right on both counts; thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jeeped Because I want to run this from Powershell, macros are really easy to deal with in that environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Your `For Each` variable is `cell`, but your code uses `cells.Value2`.

```
For Each cell In Diff                 ' Using cell (singular)
    If cells.Value2 > 0.1 Then        ' Using cells (plural)
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
Next
```

In addition, I suspect that you have values in your range (`Diff`) that aren't numeric or are empty.